# performance hit for int + "" instead of using int.ToString()

Tags: c#

How much performance hit I will inure if I use following:

```
int i=5;
label1.Text = i + "";
```

instead of:

```
int i=5;
label1.Text = i.ToString();
```

Comment: What did you find when you measured the performance of each?

Comment: @Greg: I think if he had measured them, the question wouldn't have been posted.

Comment: Look at the generated machine code to determine exactly how adverse the effect is.
In my opinion, i + "" will call an operator whereas, i.ToString() will cause transfer of control, a function push to a stack, a pop back of the result, so theoretically, the first one should be faster.

Comment: @Greg, I understand that this kind of optimization is not (generally) needed. But this was a kind of religious argument between myself and and a colleague. I'm used to use + "";

Comment: @r3st0r3: Actually the first will also cause a transfer of control as it calls the `String.Concat` method, and it will box the integer, so it's actually slower.

Comment: get your program working, and then worry about your performance, something that doesn't work really fast still doesn't work.(though I am sure this is just a question, for the proper way to do it, just some advice)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While there may be a difference in performance between the two, ask yourself this question: will this be significant for the performance of the application?

My guess is that it will not be significant.

**Measure it and fix it** if it is.

Architecture will usually affect performance. Minor language optimization may affect performance, but in general your time is better spend attending to bottlenecks identified through actual measurement.

Answer (score 12):

The first method creates an extra object in the process, as it creates an object to box the integer in. The compiler generates this code:

```
label1.Text = String.Concat((object)i, (object)String.Empty);
```

The `Concat` method will call the `ToString` method on both parameters to get their string values, which effectively unboxes the integer before turning it into a string. It would create another extra object by concatenating the strings, but it has code to catch the special case where one of the strings are empty, so it just returns the string value of the integer.

The second method ends up doing exactly what it says.

You should avoid the first method, not primarily because it performs worse, but because it hides what you really want to do.

The performance difference will be minimal as long as you don't do this in a tight loop (I measured a speed diffence of 5-10%). The extra object that is created is short lived, so it will most likely be collected in the next garbage collection. However, there is no reason to use the first method as the second method exists and does exactly what you want, instead of causing it as a hidden side effect.

#### Edit:

Note also that the first method should be written `i + String.Empty` rather than `i + ""`, so it's not even less to type than the second method.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't profiled it, but logically the first is implicitly converting `i` to a string, creating a new empty string, and then concatenating the two. The second is merely creating a string representation (one of the three steps). (Of course, the compiler could optimize the first so that they're equivalent).

Except in a very performance-critical part of the app this difference is negligible. *More important* is the fact that the second is semantically precise -- it says exactly what you're trying to do. The first is potentially confusing. I mean, that's a common enough construct that anyone who reads it will figure it out, but, given the choice, why not pick the more readable code?

Comment: The empty string will never be created. It should be already in the string pool (String.Empty).

Answer (score 1):

Simply write a Console Application that performs one and the other in separate loops for an easily modifiable amount of times and measure how long it takes to find out?

Comment: +1 for telling how to check instead of just spitting out the answer.  "Give a man a fish, feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, feed him for a life time."

Comment: Using a profiler or taking a look at the IL code would be more reliable imo, but still a good tip. But i somehow think he knows how to do that, but asking at SO is the lazy (the programmers) way ;)

Answer (score 1):

To prove Guffas answer, heres the generated IL-Code:

```
//000015:             String s1 = number.ToString();
  IL_0004:  ldloca.s   number
  IL_0006:  call       instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString()
  IL_000b:  stloc.1
//000016:             String s2 = number + "";
  IL_000c:  ldloc.0
  IL_000d:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0012:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(object)
  IL_0017:  stloc.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Negligable.  Don't bother to pay it attention.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that the benefits (if there is one) will be negligible in favor of code readability in this particular case. The second case is obvious and quick to the reader's eye; the first one normally requires a double take.

For an operation this trivial, I personally think that readability wins out.

Answer (score 0):

I will use `label1.Text = i.ToString();` even though it has a worse performance(in fact I think it has a better performance than `i+""`). Here are some reasons:

- `i+""` seems to be a hard code, which
  brings very bad smell. If you really
  want to use + operator,
  `i+string.Empty` is better(but still
  not a good idea).
- `i.ToString()` is easier to read,
  which means "oh, i need the string of
  i, to be placed in some label". It
  presents your willing. While `i+""`
  means "put the result of adding i and
  an empty string to some label".

Comment: It definitely has a worse performance. `i.ToString()` makes 1 method call and creates a single string. `i+""` has 1 boxing operation, 1 method call (to `String.Concat`), two virtual method calls (to `ToString()`) and creates one new string (I expect the `Concat` method to be smart enough to not create a new string itself).

Comment: When string interning is turned on (the default), there is no real performance difference betreen `""` and `String.Empty`.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer, `i.ToString()` is about 20 nanoseconds (2e-8) faster than `i + ""`. In other words, there is no difference. You would have to do this operation tens of millions of times before it even made 1 second difference!

Comment: I see a speed difference of about 5-10%, so that it negligable. However, the concatenation method does create an extra object which increases the garbage throughput, and it's hard to measure the exact effect of that.